Django not recognizing app’s url and views. It keeps raising a 404 `Response`
Hi I am trying to create my first Django project and having issues getting an app to work inside my Django project. I simply am trying to map the url code 8000/home1/hello/ to display the basic text "hello world" but failing to do so. I keep getting this error code:
"Using the URLconf defined in web3.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
The current path, home1/hello, didn’t match any of these."
Here is what I have done:

created a django project named web3
created an app called home1 and added a urls.py file to this app
updated the settings.py folder INSTALLE_APPS to have  'home1.apps.Home1Config',
home1 > urls.py includes this code:

from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.hello_world, name="hello_world"),
]



home1>views.py includes this code:


from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse("you finally did it justin")

6.web3> urls.py includes this code:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from home1.views import hello_world  # Import the hello_world view function


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('home1.urls')),
]



I am pretty confident my file outlay is correct as I used the basic code to create the files (django-admin startproject web3) and (python manage.py startapp home1)

I am fully lost on this one... any help would be greatly appreciate!!!

your path to home1.urls should be home1/

Hi Justin! Has this been solved? Do you still need help?

the main issue is that the URL pattern home1/hello/ is not matching because the  web3/urls.py is including home.urls at the root URL path this means home1/hello/ will actually be matched as hello/ from the root
to fix this you should do these steps:

make sure your project structure looks like this:

web3/
    manage.py
    web3/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    home1/
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        views.py
        urls.py
        migrations/
            __init__.py



make sure home1 is added to INSTALLED_APPS
your home1/urls.py should looks like this :

from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.hello_world, name='hello_world'),
]


include home1.urls in web3/urls.py and use home1/ as prefix:

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home1/', include('home1.urls')),  
]

and finally your home1/views.py should looks like this:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def hello_world(request):
    return HttpResponse("you finally did it justin")

other things that comes to my mind:

look for any typos in your file names, function names and configuration
restart the server to ensure all changes are loaded
run django's built-in system check to identify any issues:
python manage.py check
sometimes browsers cache old responses so clearing the cache or trying an incognito window might help
use django's url resolver to verify that url pattern is correctly configured add this code to one of your views temporarily to debug:

from django.urls import resolve
print(resolve('/home1/hello/'))

I hope this helps you.

So, I have updated what you suggested, and still not working on my end....I rearranged my file structure, and added the "home1/" to the web3/urls.py in the url patterns, and made sure  'home1.apps.Home1Config', is in my INSTALLED APPS. Any other thoughts or ways to trouble shoot so that we can see where the issue lies? Could it be something with my server or the way my computer is trying to run the app?

other things that comes to my mind:

look for any typos in your file names, function names and configuration
restart the server to ensure all changes are loaded
run django's built-in system check to identify any issues: python manage.py check
sometimes browsers cache old responses so clearing the cache or trying an incognito window might help
use django's url resolver to verify that url pattern is correctly configured add this code to one of your views temporarily to debug:

from django.urls import resolve
print(resolve('/home1/hello/'))


I've edited the answer and added what I've wrote in comment

The path "home1/hello/" does not exist on your Server. Only "hello/"  and "admin/" exists.
It is a common misconception that if you include a URLconf into your root URLconf like so:
urlpatterns = [
    #•••Rest of code•••
    path('', include('home1.urls')),
]
That all routes from that app will begin with the name of the app —e.g. "home1" in the above.
This is not true. For there to exist a basename, you must give a basename.
urlpatterns = [
    #•••Rest of code•••
    path('home1/', include('home1.urls')),
]
Now all routes from that app will begin with "home1".

Hi, thanks for the response, I have made your correction but am still unable to get the app to work. When I refresh my page, only the admin/ url is working and this is the only url that the server says it recognizes in the 404 error.... Any other thoughts?

Remember to add the variable app_name = "home1" in the URLconf module of the app "home1".

@Justin543543 if this worked, consider marking as complete for posterity so that others can easily find an answer to their question.
